# How do I get all objects with a specific start date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

[image: controller method]

[image: route]

I'm trying to use a date parameter that comes in through the request and return all objects that have that date. I do not want to look at the time stamp, just the year, month, day.

Answer (score 0):

The following in the controller file of mongoose finds dates that match a specific day:

```
export const getBookingByDate = (req, res) => {
    Booking.find({start: {$gt: req.params.bookingDate}}, (err, booking) => {
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(booking);
    })
}
```